# How to create universal timeout function with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

So, i need to have some universal timeout function for my script. I will need to use this many times and i want to universalize it, so i try with that, but smthg is wrong, can u help me?

```
$.fn.timeout = function(action, time){
    setTimeout(function(){
        action;
    }, time);
    return this;
}
```

and call:

```
.timeout(
    settings_container.addClass('slide_down'), 200
);
```

Thx.

Comment: `setTimeout` is already global, why not use it directly? I see no purpose attaching it to jQuery.

Comment: `setTimeout(action, time)`

Comment: I agree with not needing to extend jquery for this functionality... naming a function that contains a timeout definition would solve your issue.

Comment: @GriffLab I believe jQuery.delay() only works for animations.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't executing the action function,

change:

```
action;
```

to:

```
action();
```

Answer (score 0):

Without having to attach to jquery:

```
GlobalObject.SpcificTimeOuttFnName = function()
{
   setTimout
   (
      // Perform some generic action
      function()
      {
         $('.settings-container').addClass("slide-down");
      },
      200
   );
}
```